# How to remove repeated padding characters in a file with script?

Tags: shell

I have a binary file, and the tail always padded by a special character, like as '0x1a'(^Z). I want to remove all
the padding characters from tail.

The problem is how to count the number of repeated bytes, then use

```
     truncate -s -NUMBER_OF_PADDINGS file
```

to delete them.

Write a C program to count and remove is possible, but that maybe too high-weight, so is there a shell command to do this kind of work?

Part of the file like this

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%X"' file

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
```

Comment: What is your binary file looks like? Try this ``hexdump -v -e '/1 "%X"' filename`` and post the output here.

Comment: @Darkman I edit the question, please check.

Comment: And you want to remove all trailing 0x1A bytes?  ```sed 's/[\\x1A]*$//' filename``` or ```sed -i 's/[\\x1A]*$//' filename``` is probably what you need.